# Save a session in WinSCP through PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, winscp

I want to save a session through PowerShell in WinSCP, but I am not able to save any session with below code. May be the PowerShell code is wrong for saving a session. I want to save the session and whenever I open WinSCP I can see that session and able to login to that. Below is the code snapshot:

```
try
{
  # Load the assembly and setup the session properties
  Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCPnet.dll"

  # Session setup options
  $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.sessionOptions -Property @{
    Protocol = ([WinSCP.Protocol]::Sftp)
    HostName = "xxx.cloud.com"
    UserName = "sftpuser_WIN_NPD" 
    PortNumber = "40022"
    #Password = ""
    SshPrivateKeyPath = "C:\key\sftp_private.ppk"
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "ssh-rsa 2048 0c:ce:5a:8a:82:f6:03:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx"
  }

  $session = New-Object WinSCP.session
}
catch 
{
  Write-Host "Error : $($_.Exception.Message)"

  exit 1
}
```

Please help me in this, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use WinSCP .NET assembly for creating stored sites for WinSCP GUI.

You have to create the site key in Windows Registry (or an INI file).
See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/config

A simple example:

```
$key = New-Item 'HKCU:\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\Sessions\My New Session' -Force
$key | New-ItemProperty -Name 'HostName' -Value 'example.com' -Force
$key | New-ItemProperty -Name 'UserName' -Value 'username' -Force
```

See also https://winscp.net/eng/docs/custom_distribution#preconfigured_site